# Changing an output's value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, outputstream

i have a color changing tool that outputs a hex value.  what i'm needing is to change that value on the end form to a color name.  there are several outputs to change, and the list of color names has 1,512 entries. so, for example, one of my outputs is cp-swbluesbbg-output, and say it returns a value of #006a66 then it should be converted to "Poseiden".

the output string is:

```
    function(event, color) {
$('.cp-swbluesbbg-output').text(color.formatted);
    /*returns the value i need to convert. i.e. #006a66*/
```

my var is set up like this (fixed to a simpler format with 1,512 entries total):

```
    var newName = {
    "#006A66" : "Poseidon SW6762",
    "#006A84" : "Blue Nile SW6776",
    "#006B55" : "Starboard SW6755",
    "#006E7F" : "Maxi Teal SW6769"} ] /*this list is 1,512 entries long*/
```

i've tried several iterations of the normal string searches, but none seem to work.
i am very new to this and having a difficult time working out a search that will return the color name based off of the output for each color.  any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(newName["#006A66"])` somewhere? It might be as easy as passing the hex code in as a key and then setting text to the value associated with that key.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the format of your color object?  Having so many tiny arrays in it makes the process much longer.  Assuming that the color values are unique, you should be able to format it like this:  `var newName = {"#006A66" : "Poseidon SW6762", "#006A84" : "Blue Nile SW6776",
 "#006B55" : "Starboard SW6755", "#006E7F" : "Maxi Teal SW6769"}`, which would make your search considerably more simple.

Comment: @talemyn - i can easily change the format of 'newName', so that won't be a big deal, other than it's so huge.  do you have a suggestion of a good way to get the value i need from the string?

Comment: Added answer . . . changing the format makes the solution much simpler.

Comment: There was a small typo in my solution for the unchanged "newName" approach . . . just fixed that.  The "change the format" solution should still be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`newName` looks like a json array.. since you are using jquery you could use [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) then in your function that gets a color as a parameter you can find the color's name with `newName[color]` where `color` is the hex code.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, the quickest way to get your value is to loop through the entire object until you find the value that you want and then break out.  Something like this:

```
for (var currentColorPair in newName) {
    if (newName.hasOwnProperty(currentColorPair)) {
        if (newName[currentColorPair][hexValue]) {
            return newName[currentColorPair][hexValue];
        }
    }
}

return "Color does not exist";
```

However, if you can update the structure of "newName" to be a more simple array, like this:

```
var newName = {
    "#006A66" : "Poseidon SW6762",
    "#006A84" : "Blue Nile SW6776",
    "#006B55" : "Starboard SW6755",
    "#006E7F" : "Maxi Teal SW6769"};
```

Then you can simply call it like this:

```
if (newName[hexValue]) {
    return newName[hexValue];
}
else {
    return "Color does not exist";
}
```

. . . or, even more simply, like this:

```
return (newName[hexValue]) ? newName[hexValue] : "Color does not exist";
```

Comment: this seems pretty straight forward, but i am not able to make it work.  i have reset the structure of the `newName` `var`, and set `var` for `hexValue` to `document.getElementsByClassName("cp-bluesbbg-output").value;` but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I notice in your sample code that you have `#006a66` listed as the value that is being returned, while the value in the array is `#006A66`.  The case will matter when it looks for the value, so, since all of your array data appears to be in uppercase, try updating your code to `document.getElementsByClassName("cp-bluesbbg-output").value.toUpperCase();` and see if that helps.